# On the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n + (-2)^n}{n } x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have studied with my classmates the following series in class:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n + (-2)^n}{n } x^n$$

where $x \in C$, this series is in the form such that one can apply the Cauchy–Hadamard theorem, so to find the radius of convergence we can compute

$$\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg( \frac{2^n + (-2)^n}{n } \Bigg)^{1/n}$$

I wrote that because $  (2^{2k+1}/ 2k)^{1/2k} \rightarrow 2$ then we have shown that the limit is $2$. My doubt is: is this some kind of Cauchy condensation test for limits of sequences? I only know the one for series.  Could I have a reference to study it or is it something else entirely?

Comment: I don't understand you question: "is this some kind of Cauchy condensation test for limits of sequences?" How is that related to what you had said before that? Also, you've already found the radius of convergence for the series, so what else are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My question is why does $(2^{2k+1}/ 2k)^{1/2k} \rightarrow 2$ imply that  $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg( \frac{2^n + (-2)^n}{n } \Bigg)^{1/n} \rightarrow 2$ , we have a subsequence of our original sequence but the convergence of the subsequence is not enough to guarantee the convergence of the sequence. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: Yes, but the other subsequence is 0, dividing the original sequence completely into disjoint subsequences. Thus you know the two limit points of the root sequence, and with that the limes superior.

Comment: Also note that the value of the series is $\ln(1+2x)+\ln(1-2x)=\ln(1-4x^2)$. Suggesting to remove the zeros and write the series as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4^k·(x^2)^k}{k}$.

Comment: @LutzL thank you very much! I understand now my question, but could you elaborate a bit more on your second comment? when do we apply $\ln$?

Comment: This is just the application of the logarithm series, but probably with a wrong sign. $-\ln(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}n$, and thus there should be a minus sign before the whole expression. For your question, it is not necessary to know this.